# Quiero enviar mi localización por email mediante un plugin de cordova pero sale Undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova

Estoy implementado varios plugins como lo son geolocalización, email, y cámara. Intento tomar una foto y enviar esa misma foto que tomé con la ubicación por email pero al tratar de enviarla me sale UNDEFINED al tratar de mostrar mi localización.

```
var latid = 0;
var long = 0;

function Capturar(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(exitoso) 
       
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {  
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth:300,
        targetHeight:300,
        correctOrientation:true,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
        cameraDirection: 1
        });
    }
    
    function onSuccess(imageData) {

       
                var image = document.getElementById('foto');
                foto.style.display = 'block';
                image.src = imageData; //"data:image/jpeg;base64," +
                document.getElementById('archivo').innerHTML = imageData;
                }  
                               
                function onFail(message) {
                alert('Error: ' + message);
                }


function exitoso(posicion){
        

     latid = posicion.coords.latitude;
     long = posicion.coords.longitude;

    document.getElementById('datos').innerHTML = 'Latitud: ' + latid + '<br>' +

    'Longitud: ' + long +'<br>';

 }

function enviar(latid, long ){

        cordova.plugins.email.open({
        
        to: 'lanc59323@gmail.com',
        
        cc: 'lanc59323@gmail.com',
        
        subject: ['prueba',],
        
        attachments:  [onSuccess.image],
        
        body: [' Es mi ubicación de donde tome la imagen' + ' <div id="datos"> </div>' + latid + long] ,

        isHtml: true
        
        });
        
    }
```